# Extrema for Single Variable Functions (2nd Deriv Test)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Using the 2nd derivative test, we know that if the value from evaluating critical points at the 2nd derivative is greater than 0, then it is a *local min*. If the value is less than 0, then it is a *local max*.

However, if the value is = 0, then it is "inconclusive".

What does this mean? Is it considered an inflection point/saddle point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful:  $f''(c) > 0$ implies local min, not max.

It may not be an inflection point; this all depends on the particular function.  It is indeed inconclusive.  Consider $f(x) = x^4$.  Clearly $x=0$ is critical, but $f''(0)=0$.  But still, $x=0$ clearly gives a local min and is not an inflection point. The function $f(x)=x^3$ shows that the critical point may be an inflection point.

Comment: ahh, edited****